# Node.js : How to convert stdout complicated text output from ffmpeg into a buffer

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, buffer

`��\b�b��� �!zGo~3f\x14<\x02���jǧ�3�R�\x01L��Oj{Qd���r;��\t�I\x10\x13y�pJr��e?\x17\x12-�i����l��"����Т\x1C�\x002<Ҹ�L)E\t�(֠.̸�i��s\t�....

Result of below code is complicated

`ffmpeg -i freevideo.mp4 -r 24 -f image2pipe -`

this image was exectued on node.js child_process and output was shown in unix cli

I want to change this complicated string to buffer into nodejs
after that want to upload BufferImage into S3

Question

- How can I do
- What is format this complicated string